# Not able to see the archive option

Tags: archive, archive-utility

Just got a new mac. When I right click a .zip file, I don't see the Decompress/Archive option. Do I need to download something or change a configuration option?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the file and choose Open. This will automatically decompress the file with the built-in Archive Utility.

Comment: Or just double-click the file :-)